# How to find an index by content via input() in pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find an index based on the content of a table, which in this case is a string in the form of a date 'd/m/YYYY' or 'dd/mm/YYYY' for 2-digit days and months respectively. I am looking for the 1st of a specific month which i want to find interactively using input().

The code works fine as long as i hardcode the month:

```
stream = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
for path in stream:
    df = pd.read_csv('{}'.format(path))
    df['Idx'] = df['Date'].str.contains('^1/8/20\d{2} 0:00:00')
    index_month = df[df['Idx']==True].index.values.astype(int)[0]
    print('Index was found at {}'.format(month, index_month))
```

Output:

```
Index was fount at 19516
Index was found at 19527
...
...
```

but gives

`ValueError: cannot switch from automatic field numbering to manual field specification`

when i use `input()` to find the respective month (see code below)

```
print("Enter Month as number:")
month=input()

stream = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
for path in stream:
    df = pd.read_csv('{}'.format(path))
    df['Idx'] = df['Date'].str.contains('^1/{}/20\d{2} 0:00:00'.format(month))
    index_month = df[df['Idx']==True].index.values.astype(int)[0]
    print('Index was found at {}'.format(month, index_month))
```

The error is traced back to

```
df['Idx'] = df['Date'].str.contains('^1/{}/20\d{2} 0:00:00'.format(month))
```

Is it possible to solve it this way, or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is simply here:

```py
'^1/{}/20\d{2} 0:00:00'
```

`{2}` is interpreted by str's `format` method, so you need to escape it using double braces:

```
>>> month = 3
>>> re.search('^1/{}/20\d{{2}} 0:00:00'.format(month), '1/3/2020 0:00:00').group()
'1/3/2020 0:00:00'
```